# How to declare events efficiently on div

Tags: javascript, html

Which is the fastest way to declare multiple event listeners in JavaScript. Should I do it like this:

```
 <div onclick="myFunction();">
   <div>Element 1</div>
   <div>Element 2</div> 
 </div>
```

Or like this:

```
 <div>
   <div onclick="myFunction();">Element 1</div>
   <div onclick="myFunction();">Element 2</div> 
 </div>
```

Does anybody have any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add event listeners to the child `<div>`s like so:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("#containerDiv div"), div => {
    div.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you need to do. Inline event handlers are not recommended anyway. If you give your divs a class and the container an ID or a class, you can do proper event handling

```
document.querySelector("#containerDiv").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  var clickedDiv = e.target;
  if (e.target.classList.contains('div1') {
    console.log("I am div 1");
  }
});
```

If you want to add event listeners to the inner divs, you can loop

```
// a simple loop. You can use ES6 and polyfills if you want to be more modern
var divs = document.querySelectorAll("#containerDiv div");
for (var i=0;i<divs.length;i++) {
  divs[i].addEventListener("click",function(e) {
    console.log(this.textContent); // here you have direct access to the clicked div
  });
}
```

Here is a good article on looping nodeLists

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am confused with this so i need to use `loop` for multiple elements right ?

Comment: Not if you add the event handler to the container, but otherwise yes. See update